# Meaning Of Environment Variables in Asp.Net core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I need help, i need someone to explain in the most basic way possible so i, a dummy can understand what environment variables are and ho they affect my code. i noticed that when i remove some classes with the environment include or exclude tags it affects my web app performance.

```
<environment exclude="Development">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter- 
      bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      asp-fallback-href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      asp-fallback-test-class="sr-only" asp-fallback-test-property="position" asp-fallback-test- 
      value="absolute"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
      integrity="sha256-eSi1q2PG6J7g7ib17yAaWMcrr5GrtohYChqibrV7PBE="/>
</environment>


<environment include="Development">
  <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.js"></script>
  </environment>
<environment exclude="Development">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"
        asp-fallback-src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
        asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery"
        crossorigin="anonymous"
        integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=">
</script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter- 
        bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        asp-fallback-src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery && window.jQuery.fn && window.jQuery.fn.modal"
        crossorigin="anonymous"
        integrity="sha256-E/V4cWE4qvAeO5MOhjtGtqDzPndRO1LBk8lJ/PR7CA4=">
 </script>
</environment>
<script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
@RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
```

i don't understand at all what this means but i know if i remove it, a dropdown toggle button on my web app layout page doesn't function but if i put the above block of codes back my toggle button works but another dashboard toggle button on the same layout does not work...i have tried to check online but i don't seem to understand what anyone is saying about it .

note i used a custom layout and added my style and scripts libraries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Environment Tag Helper(<environment></environment>)` is used to display content based on the application hosting environment.

For example: Whenever you are running your application in your local machine from Visual Studio `IISExress`, by default environment variable of the application is `Development`. So in this case following content will not be shown because you are telling that content inside `<environment></environment>` should be exclude from rendering with `exclude="Development"` attribute value:

```
<environment exclude="Development"> // This will be shown in all environment except Development
      <span>Don't render this</span>
</environment>
```

But following content inside `<environment></environment>` will be shown because you are telling to render the content inside `<environment></environment>` with `include="Development"` attribute value.

```
<environment include="Development"> // This will be shown only in Development environment
      <span>Render this</span>
</environment>
```

Hope it is clear to you now!

For more details: [Environment Tag Helper in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/environment-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-3.0)

Comment: @AjumobiOlamide assets local link in the development and cdn links in the other than development (for production).

Comment: so for example if i include  just a script link in the development environment, so;            1. does it mean only that script link(say a jquery link) would accessible by the browser in development mode and other script links that i put at the head tag and are not in the environment include or exclude are not accessible.  2)for another environment variable say Production, is that script link(jquery) link accessible  by the browser?